# How to debug a Scala application from IntelliJ Idea [akka-http, sbt]

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to debug my `sbt` project which is an `akka-http` server.

I am using `postman` for hitting routes. When I start the debugging in idea by right clicking the main class and chose debug, debug window started and when I hit the route from postman, the debug window content disappears and the variable tab shows `the application is running`.

I want to see what happens when I hit the route. That's what we do with debugging. Maybe I am not running the debugger correctly. Please guide me I have never done it previously. Also I run sbt commands for my projects from sbt shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sbt shell` to run your application.

[image]

Click `Attach debbugger to sbt shell` (green icon in `sbt shell` tab)

[image]

and run your application from sbt shell then. Debugger should work. It will stop your application on fist breakpoint as expected:

[image]

[image]